# Cannot recognize step definition file from glue with cucumber ant task

Tags: ant, cucumber

I have my feature file in /src/test/resources/features/InputFileVal.feature and step definition file in sr/test/java/steps/InputFileValSteps.java.

Attaching complete build.xml and class path details from property.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="DSP" basedir="." default="usage">

    <description>HP DSP Ant Build file</description>

    <!-- Global properties file -->
    <import file="${basedir}/properties.xml"/>

    <!-- Deployment specific property file -->
    <property file="${basedir}/config.properties" />

    <!-- Ensure that the JVM version is 1.7 -->
    <target name="get-jvm">
        <condition property="jvm.ok">
            <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.7" />
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="check-jvm" depends="get-jvm" unless="jvm.ok">
        <echo message="Checking JVM Version.." />
        <fail message="Wrong JVM - ${ant.java.version}, DSP requires Java 1.7" />
    </target>

    <!-- check build environment -->
    <target name="check-environment" depends="check-jvm">
        <echo message="Checking ANT version and Availability of required JAR files.." />

        <!-- Ensure that Ant 1.6.2+ is being used -->
        <available classname="org.apache.tools.ant.DynamicAttribute" property="ant-1.6.2" />
        <fail unless="ant-1.6.2" message="HP DSP requires Ant 1.6.2 or higher for building" />
    </target>

    <target name="init" description="defines custom tasks" depends="check-environment">
        <echo message="HP DSP Build Initialization Passed..." />
    </target>

    <!-- clean the dist folder -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${dist.dir}" />
        </delete>
        <delete dir="${basedir}/xmlBeans/" />
    </target>

    <!-- Redeploys war file to the local jboss 'default' instance -->
    <target name="deploy" depends="war">

        <delete file="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments/dsp.war" failonerror="no" />
        <sleep seconds="4"/>
        <copy file="${basedir}/dist/dsp.war" todir="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments/" overwrite="yes" />

    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="dist-compile">
        <antcall target="copyPropertyFiles"/>
        <antcall target="copyAdditionalFiles"/>
        <echo level="info" message="copied all files to ${dist.dir}, packaging as WAR file." />
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${webapp.name}.war" basedir="${webapp.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="cucumber-compile" depends="dist-compile">

            <description>Compile the test Java code</description>
            <javac srcdir="${test.java.dir}" destdir="${web-classes.dir}" classpathref="compile.classpath" debug="${javac.debug}"/>
        </target>


    <target name="dist-compile" depends="prepare">
        <description>Compile the UDCR Java code</description>
        <javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${web-classes.dir}" classpathref="compile.classpath" debug="${javac.debug}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="prepare">
        <description>Compile the UDCR Java code</description>
        <javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="compile.classpath" debug="${javac.debug}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="prepare" depends="init,clean,createFolders">
        <!--<fixcrlf srcdir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.properties" eol="lf"/>
        <fixcrlf srcdir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.xml" eol="lf"/> -->
        <echo level="info" message="Initialization Passed." />
    </target>

    <!-- create empty directories in the dist folder -->
    <target name="createFolders">
        <echo level="info" message="Creating empty directories" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${webapp.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${web-inf.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${web-classes.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${web-lib.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${web-schema.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${web-wsdl.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${cucumber-report.dir}" />
    </target>


    <target name="copyPropertyFiles">
        <echo message="Copying spring-conf, i18n and other properties to ${web-classes.dir}" />
        <!-- Convert the i18n files to UTF-8 -->
        <native2ascii encoding="UTF-8" src="${resources.dir}/i18n" dest="${web-classes.dir}/i18n" includes="*.properties" />

        <!-- Copy the spring configuration files to the target folder -->
        <copy todir="${web-classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resources.dir}/">
                <include name="spring-conf/**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${web-classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resources.dir}/">
                <include name="**"/>
                <exclude name="i18n/**"/>
                <exclude name="spring-conf/**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <!-- move overwrite="true" file="${web-classes.dir}/spring-conf/dsm-security-saml.xml" tofile="${web-classes.dir}/spring-conf/dsm-security.xml" / -->
    </target>


    <target name="copyAdditionalFiles">
        <echo message="Copying additional required files for the WAR file..." />

        <!-- Copy the common files to the webapp folder -->
        <copy todir="${webapp.dir}" includeEmptyDirs="no">
            <fileset dir="${build.webapp.dir}/">
                <include name="**"/>
                <exclude name="WEB-INF/**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <!-- Copy the jsp and lib files to the WEB-INF folder -->
        <copy todir="${web-inf.dir}" includeEmptyDirs="no">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}/">
                <include name="*.xml"/>
                <include name="*.tld"/>
                <include name="pages/**"/>
                <include name="lib/**"/>
                <include name="schema/*.xsd"/>
                <include name="wsdl/*.wsdl"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="copy_war_to_JBoss" >
        <echo message="Copying war to JBoss server" />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${jboss.home}\standalone\deployments\dsp.war" includes="**/*"/>
        </delete>

        <copy todir="${jboss.home}\standalone\deployments\dsp.war" >
            <fileset dir="${basedir}\src\main\webapp\">
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="cucumber" depends="cucumber-compile">
    <java classname="io.cucumber.core.cli.Main" fork="true" failonerror="false"
        classpathref ="compile.classpath">
                        <arg value="--plugin"/>
                        <!-- creates our junit report -->
                        <arg value="junit:${cucumber-report.dir}/InputFileValidation.xml"/>
                        <arg value="--plugin"/>
                        <arg value="pretty"/>
                        <arg value="--plugin"/>
                        <!-- creates our cucumber html friendly report -->
                        <arg value="html:${cucumber-report.dir}/cucumber-html-report"/>
                        <arg value="--plugin"/>
                        <!-- creates our cucumber json friendly report -->
                        <arg value="json:${cucumber-report.dir}/cucumber.json"/>

                        <arg value="--glue"/>
                        <arg value="src/test/java/steps"/>
                        <arg value="src/test/resources"/>
                    </java>
        <!-- writes out information to junit report -->
                    <junitreport todir="${cucumber-report.dir}">
                        <fileset dir="${cucumber-report.dir}">
                            <include name="InputFileValidation.xml"/>
                        </fileset>
                        <report format="frames" todir="${cucumber-report.dir}"/>
                    </junitreport>

                    <!-- checks our exit status, and determines success or failure -->
                    <fail message="Cucumber failed">
                        <condition>
                            <not>
                                <equals arg1="${cucumber.exitstatus}" arg2="0"/>
                            </not>
                        </condition>
                    </fail>
                </target>

    <!-- Default target -->
    <target name="usage">
        <echo message="------------------------------------------------------"   />
        <echo message="HP DSP build options"                                     />
        <echo message="------------------------------------------------------"   />
        <echo message="Available targets are :"                                  />
        <echo message="clean          --> Deletes all files in dist folder."     />
        <echo message="compile        --> Compiles DSP java sources."            />
        <echo message="war            --> Create a deployable WAR file of DSP."  />
        <echo message="deploy         --> Redeploys war to local JBoss instance."/>
        <echo message="------------------------------------------------------"   />
    </target>


</project>

Class path details from property.xml
    <!--  CLASSPATH for compilation -->
    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${build.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${extralib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${test.resources.dir}/features" />
    </path>
```

But when I run the build it complains about steps being unimplemented. I verified the path of step definition package given in glue arg.

Please help me as what could be going wrong?

Note: I tried a lot of google suggestions but I have ended up in getting nothing. I am using jdk7 and ant   because of the legacy project implementation.

Comment: Could you please change the glue value from steps to src/test/java/steps/

Comment: @UnknownBeast: Even that doesnt work. Can you suggest anything else? I cannot understand what is wrong because I verified in lot of blogs..

Comment: Could you please share your project with us. So that we can try to find the root cause.

Comment: @UnknownBeast: I edited the question to add the complete build.xml